# Batch file fore creating base HTML files & folders

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create a batch file to create the basic files & folders for a website, e.g. css folder, image folder, javascript folder, style.css, index.html. I have the script setup as follows

```
md css
md js
md img
echo  ^<!doctype html^>^<html lang="en"^>^<head^>^<meta charset="UTF-8"^>^<title^>^Document^</title^>^</head^>^<body^>^</body^>^</html^>  >>  index.html
echo  >>style.css
```

As you can see, I want to input the basic html starter text within the html file, which it does, but all in a straight line. While this isn't the end of the world, it would be nice if it could format the text as proper html with indents and line breaks.

One more thing, would it be possible to make the batch file put the css file in the css folder? I am a bit of a n00b, so be gentle :0)

Thanks!

**UPDATE**
Here is the code I did upon reading the response from @Endoro

```
md css
md js
md img
echo  ^<!doctype html^>
echo  ^<html lang="en"^>
echo  ^<head^>
echo ^ <meta charset="UTF-8"^>
echo  ^<title^>
echo  ^</title^>
echo  ^</head^>
echo  ^<body^>
echo  ^</body^>
echo  ^</html^> >> index.html
echo  >>css\style.css
```

It kind of works in that it puts the css file in the css folder, but when I open the html file, all that is present is

```
</html>
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: You missed the brackets at top and end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know, what indents you need, but you can edit the code by yourself:

```
@echo off &setlocal
md css 2>nul
md js 2>nul
md img 2>nul
(
echo(^<!doctype html^>^<html lang="en"^>
echo(   ^<head^>^<meta charset="UTF-8"^>
echo(       ^<title^>^Document^</title^>
echo(   ^</head^>
echo(   ^<body^>^</body^>^</html^>
)>index.html
echo(>css\style.css
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is how you do it. The problem is, is that you didn't add the `>> index.HTML`.
Here is the correct solution that I think works, (not tested):

```
md css
md js
md img
echo  ^<!doctype html^> >> index.html
echo  ^<html lang="en"^> >> index.html
echo  ^<head^> >> index.html
echo  ^<meta charset="UTF-8"^> >> index.html
echo  ^<title^> >> index.html
echo  ^</title^> >> index.html
echo  ^</head^> >> index.html
echo  ^<body^> >> index.html
echo  ^</body^> >> index.html
echo  ^</html^> >> index.html
echo  >>css\style.css
```

Answer (score 0):

Break up the `index.html` output into separate `echo` commands and it will insert linefeeds for you, between the output of each individual `echo`.

And specify the css filename as `css\style.css` and it should create the file in that folder.